# Count field incorrect error while connecting eclipse to ODBC driver

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ms-access

I got this error while trying to create a record into database using microsoft access and eclipse.

```
    [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect
```

And the Connection showed is closed. Here is my codes to connect to the ODBC driver.

```
    public class DBController {
private Connection con;

public void setUp(String dsn) {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Load driver error");
    }
    try {

        String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ResultSet readRequest(String dbQuery) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(dbQuery);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}

public int updateRequest(String dbQuery) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        count = stmt.executeUpdate(dbQuery);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count;
}

public void terminate() {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And these are my codes to createUser.

```
        public boolean createUser() {
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "INSERT INTO forumUsers(users_userName,users_password,users_NRIC,users_securityQuestion,users_answer) ";
    sql += "VALUES ('" + userName + "','" + pwd + "','" + nric + "','"
            + securityQuestion + "','" + answer + "')";
    System.out.println(sql);
    if (db.updateRequest(sql) == 1)
        success = true;
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

I already rearrange the sequence by following the database table column but it still showing the count field incorrect error. So how can I fix it? Any help will be appreciated.
And this is my swing.

```
    public void submitSignup(ActionEvent e) {
    String userName = jTextField_userName.getText();
    String pwd = new String(jPasswordField.getPassword());
    String nric = jTextField_nric.getText();
    String securityQuestion = jComboBox_securityQuestion.getSelectedItem()
            .toString();
    String answer = jTextField_answer.getText();

    if (userName.equals("") || pwd.equals("") || nric.equals("")
            || securityQuestion.equals("") || answer.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter all text field");
    else {
        eForumUser user = new eForumUser(userName, pwd, nric,
                securityQuestion, answer);
        if (user.isExist())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "User already exists! Cannot create.");
        else {
            if (user.createUser() == true)
                ;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "User record created successfull!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i editted already. Is it my sequence went wrongly?

Comment: *"Is it my sequence went wrongly?"*  If by 'sequence' you mean the order in which you added tags, posted the question, then added code that fit the tags, then yes.  Do it all at once.  Otherwise I have no idea what that sentence means.

Comment: Hmm what I mean is should I use the Insert statement according to the sequence of my database column?

Comment: I have no idea.  I know Swing, not D/Bs.

Comment: Can somebody explain to me what does COUNT field incorrect means?

Comment: @GabrielHeng This has nothing to do with Swing. But does your insert statement work when you try it directly on DB. if so than I have no clue. I would suggest surrounding code with try catch blocks in order to pinpoint the line thats giving the error.

Comment: Your code is very fragile and is a security hole for SQL-injection. Imagine someone enters the following user name: "`','','','','');DELETE FROM forumUsers;INSERT INTO forumUsers(users_userName,users_password,users_NRIC,users_securityQuestion,users_answer) 
VALUES ('`". Funny thing, isn't it? Use `PreparedStatement`'s instead or use JPA, they will protect you against SQL-injection. As for your error, it may be because you misspelled one of your fields in the insert statement.

Comment: David Kroukamp - Ya it works for my another workshop which only insert two data which is ID and password. However, it does not work with this.

Guillaume Polet - We are still at the learning stage of sql. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. I'll look thru it later :)

Comment: @GabrielHeng _"Ya it works for my another workshop which only insert two data which is ID and password"_ If in this case it does not work, as I suggested in my previous comment, this may be due to an incorrect field spelling or the field simply does not exist in your Table. Impossible to tell without seeing the rest of your code and the table you created.

Comment: Okay okay I will try to double check everything again. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO forumUsers(users_userName,users_password,users_NRIC,users_securityQuestion,users_answer) " +
         "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            System.out.println(sql);
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,users_userName);
            ps.setString(2,users_password);
            ps.setString(3,users_NRIC);
            ps.setString(4,users_securityQuestion);
            ps.setString(5,users_answer);
            int checks = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(checks != 0){                
                  success = true;                       
            }
            else{
              System.out.println("Failed to insert user data");
            }
 db.terminate();
```